# How to find which app/process change my network proxy on my Mac Studio running macOS Ventura 13.1?

Tags: macos, proxy

My Mac Studio is running macOS Ventura 13.1 and every time when I turn off all switch of proxy settings, after a few minutes, it changes to this:

[image: proxy settings]

But no process is listening this port. How to find which app/process change my network proxy on my mac studio? Is there any system log?

Answer (score 0):

This is generally caused by **Charles**/**Burp** proxy or other network sniffer tools that you have on your machine.

Check in the *startup items* to make sure not start on every boot, or change settings to avoid change proxy / network settings automatically.